# Extjs chart shadow

Tags: charts, extjs4, shadow, extjs-chart

I have the following code to contruct a pie chart.
The problem is i don't get a shadow.
Note : If the chart config, **theme='Base'**, then the pie has a shadow

```
Ext.define('ChartPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    //------------------CONSTRUCTOR  
    , constructor: function(externalConfigs) {
        externalConfigs = externalConfigs || {}; 

        var configs = {
            title: 'My panel',
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'chart',
                store: myStore,
                width: '30%',
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie'
                        , field: 'persentage'
                        , shadow: 'sides'
                        , showInLegend: false
                        , donut: false
                        , renderer: function(sprite, record, attributes, index, store) {
                            if (record.data.description == 'option1') {
                                sprite.setAttributes({
                                    fill: 'url(#redGradient)',
                                    stroke: '#ffffff'
                                }, false);
                            } else if (record.data.description == 'option2') {
                                sprite.setAttributes({
                                    fill: 'url(#greenGradient)',
                                    stroke: '#ffffff'
                                }, false);
                            }
                        }
                   }]
                   , gradients: [{
                        id: 'redGradient',
                        angle: 45,
                        stops: {
                            0: { color: '#820000' },
                            100: { color: '#BD1E00' }
                        }                        
                    }, {
                        id: 'greenGradient',
                        angle: 0,
                        stops: {
                            0: { color: '#89AC10' },
                            100: { color: '#A1C22D' }
                        }
                    }]
                } 
            ]
            }

            Ext.apply(configs, externalConfigs);
            this.callParent([configs]); //Call the parent constructor
        }


    });
```

Any ideas how to get a shadow?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`shadow: true`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.chart.Chart-cfg-shadow) (see the docs in the previous link to see other possible options) within your `chart` definition. (Not within the `pie` definition). There is no `shadow` config property for `Ext.chart.series.Pie`. You would need to use [`shadowAttributes`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Pie-cfg-shadowAttributes) within `Ext.chart.series.Pie`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The shadow:true does nothing if the series renderer set the attribute to even one sprite.But let me ask you.Where in the heck can i find the shadowAttributes options?

Comment: That's a really good question. Best I can suggest is to look at the source for Ext.chart.series.Pie, and you'll note they use the following options:"stroke-width": 6,
                "stroke-opacity": 1,
                stroke: 'rgb(200, 200, 200)',
                translate: {
                    x: 1.2,
                    y: 2
                }

Answer (score 1):

I found that

```
return attributes;
```

inside the renderer is essential.